# Google Analytics Cross Domain and UTM Parameter Tracking

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I have a client who run Facebook Ads with UTM parameters attached to the CTA link URLs. These link to the client's consumer site (Site A) then the user travels to the client's online ordering platform (Site B) to complete a purchase.

Our GTM container and measurement ID are the same across both sites, and I've enabled cross domain tracking in the GA4 data stream settings for Site B. The problem is the final purchase event information can't be matched up with the UTM campaign name regardless of filtering by First User Campaign or Session Campaign. I can see certain precheck out events like add to carts and item views associated with a UTM campaign name, but I can't see anything past the begin checkout event.

Everything I've read indicates that if cross domain tracking is enabled, and the measurement ID is used by both sites, that I should be able to see a final dollar value associated with the UTM campaign name. I have noticed that the _gl*xxxxxx* and subsequent cross domain info is present on the first page of Site B when a user comes from Site A, but this information disappears from the URL after the user goes to individual product pages or to the checkout page. It's probably an obvious answer, but does the cross domain url info need to be in all page urls for cross domain tracking to work? If it does, what about Site B would be removing this from the URL?

I've checked the GA setup, I've checked the tags, I've made sure the measurement code is on all pages, but I still can't figure out why I'm unable to see an association between the purchase event data and UTM campaign name.

Comment: .......Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but would like to share what I've discovered. I'm using GA4 and having similar problems which you shared. I've Website A on one domain and Website B which performs the transaction sitting on a different domain. The Website A will not pass any UTM params when redirected to Website B to complete the same. My understanding is if I configured both sites in the same GA4 property with proper cross-domain settings, the UTM params should work as expected.

However, this is not the case and my Website A has been captured as referral in the reports.

I debugged further by inspecting the sites in GTM preview mode and checking the pageview action in GA4 debug view. I found out that if the UTM params are passed correctly, the "source" for the page view should not display anything upon arriving to Website B. This is not the case even with proper GA4 cross-domain setup. I might need to ensure the UTM params are passed correctly.

My assumption previously was if the GA cross-domain is setup correctly, the UTM params should sync up as well, but I guess I'm wrong.